# How to fix the bit rate of ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am building simple java application to broadcast the webcam to the server listening on

```
localhost:8082
```

with following java program

```
private String frameRate = "60";
private String bitRate = "100k";

private String param = " -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video  -r "+frameRate+" -b:v "+bitRate+" http://localhost:8082/raj/640/480/";
private String command  =" ffmpeg ";

//to execute

proc = rt.exec(command +" "+param);
proc.waitFor();
```

Following is the output from starting point to 5 sec.

```
frame=   27 fps=  0 q=5.4 size=      88kB time=0.43 bitrate=1655.4kbits/s dup=18 drop=0    
frame=   59 fps= 55 q=11.6 size=     146kB time=0.97 bitrate=1238.3kbits/s dup=45 drop=0    
frame=   94 fps= 60 q=26.1 size=     207kB time=1.55 bitrate=1095.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  125 fps= 60 q=14.3 size=     235kB time=2.07 bitrate= 929.9kbits/s dup=83 drop=0    
frame=  156 fps= 60 q=16.1 size=     276kB time=2.58 bitrate= 875.5kbits/s dup=97 drop=0    
frame=  187 fps= 60 q=15.4 size=     306kB time=3.10 bitrate= 807.9kbits/s dup=111 drop=0    
frame=  218 fps= 60 q=22.1 size=     343kB time=3.62 bitrate= 777.8kbits/s dup=125 drop=0    
frame=  249 fps= 60 q=24.8 size=     379kB time=4.13 bitrate= 751.7kbits/s dup=139 drop=0    
frame=  280 fps= 60 q=31.0 size=     402kB time=4.65 bitrate= 708.8kbits/s dup=153 drop=0    
frame=  311 fps= 60 q=31.0 size=     436kB time=5.17 bitrate= 690.7kbits/s dup=167 drop=0    
frame=  342 fps= 60 q=31.0 size=     458kB time=5.68 bitrate= 659.5kbits/s dup=181 drop=0
```

Initially, bit rate is ok, but it is in decreasing order. Is this due to java program or ffmped. How to fix the bit rate?

Answer (score 0):

If the image has low motion, ( like a security camera ) the encoder may not need any more than 700kbits to encode the image. If you look at the q value, it is at 31 (31 is the max) so the quantizer is encoding at the highest quality possible and still can hit the target bit rate. You can increase the resolution to give the encoder more work to go, or you can add padding.  Or you can just enjoy the bandwidth savings :)